# If statement with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I can do an if statement with this code. The if statement is supposed to determine whether or not the li gets a class name or not depending on if its read or not. What determines it is the data[x][messageRead] == 0 or not but not sure how to do this inside of this append.

```
$.each(data, function(x)
{
    $('.mail').append('<li><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>'); 
});
```

Comment: Lots of good solutions here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just javascript...

```
$.each(data, function(x)
{
    if (data[x][messageRead] == 0) {
        $('.mail').append('<li><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>');
    } else {
        $('.mail').append('<li class="read"><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>');
    }
});
```

You can refactor a bit but principle is like anything else

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [ternary operator ?:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
$.each(data, function(x)
{
    $('.mail').append('<li' + (data[x][messageRead] == 0 ? 'class="ClassName"' : '') + '><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For such cases it is advised to use the method `.toggleClass()` from the jQuery API

> http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 1):

The actual value gets passed to the second value of your callback. Then you create the li element first and then use a strict equality comparison if you should add the class:

```
$.each(data, function(x, value)
{
    var li = $('<li><a href=""><strong>Received: '+ value.dateSent +'</strong><small>'+ value.subject +'</small><small>From: '+ value.firstName+' '+ value.lastName +'</small></a></li>');
    if(value.messageRead === 0) {
        li.addClass('the-class');
    }
    $('.mail').append(li);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the ternary operator

```
$.each(data, function(x)
{
    $('.mail').append('<li' + (data[x][messageRead] == 0 ? ' class="yourclass"' : '')><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>'); 
});
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(x)
{
    $('.mail').append('<li' + (data[x][messageRead] == 0 ? ' class="myClass"' : '') + '><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(x)
{
    $('.mail').append('<li class="' + ((data[x][messageRead] == 0)?'read':'unread') + '"><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>'); 
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would give you what you want.

```
$.each(data, function(x)
{
    var item = $('<li><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>');
    if(data[x]['messageRead'] == 0){
        item.addClass('new');
    }
    $('.mail').append(item); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator, and add the class only if your criteria is met.

For readability I store the class in variable, but it could of course be done within the append as well.

```
$.each(data, function(x)
{
    var classString = (data[x]['messageRead'] == 0) ? " class=\"read\"" : "";
    $('.mail').append('<li' + classString +'><a href=""><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>'); 
});
```